# Dynamic Content Function (callable from front page .aspx, not code behind)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a sort-of CMS set up so staff members can edit website content on our new website instead of submitting requests to us. I need to write a function that I can call from within my .aspx (front end) file. So I have a div and I want to make my function call from within it such as:

```
<div class='content-section'>
    <% //call function here %>
</div>
```

My first thought was to make it a function in the code behind of Site.Master, but I was having issues calling it. I'm not the most versatile C# developer, so some guidance would be nice. The Function essentially just returns a string (fetched from a database) containing page content

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern to have C# code in ASPX itself:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat=server>

protected String MethodThatReturnsStringFromDB()
{
    // do the DB logic
    return "stringfromdb";
}

</script>
<html>
 <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div class='content-section'>
     <% =MethodThatReturnsStringFromDB()%>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and if you want to use this method from several pages, then you can try putting it in the master page as follows and use it in child pages:

master page aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat=server>

public String MethodInMasterPageThatReturnsStringFromDB()
{
    // do the DB logic
    return "stringfromdb";
}

</script>
<html>
 <!-- site.master markup -->
</html>
```

here is the child page code:

1. ensure master page is referenced by type. (else you need to cast it)
2. call the master page's method.

You can use the @MasterType directive to avoid the cast

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/site.master" %>

<div class='content-section'>
 <% =Page.Master.MethodInMasterThatReturnsStringFromDB()%>
</div>
```

without the @MasterType directive, it would be:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" %>

<div class='content-section'>
 <% =(Page.Master as MasterPageType).MethodInMasterThatReturnsStringFromDB()%>
</div>
```

Comment: So I'd have to do this on a per-page basis? No really easy way to have one function globally?

Comment: sure you can.. edited the answer to handle that scenario as well

Comment: had to do several edits due to some code formatting issues.. finally got there

Comment: Btw I have put the master page method inline in aspx of master. You can put it in code behind of master as well. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So here's what I've done (in master page):
`<script runat="server">protected string fetchContentByID(int id){return "Test, Test, Test";}</script>`

And then in my content page: 

`<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>`

And then making my function call: 

`<div class="content-slide" id="brainstorm-experience"><%= Page.Master.fetchContentByID(1) %></div>`

Comment: I get the following error: 


`'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'fetchContentByID' and no extension method 'fetchContentByID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Did I leave something out or?

Comment: Your first answer, including the function on every page, works properly. Which, is definitely the easiest solution I've found, but hopefully I can get it to work using the master page!

Comment: Try making the function public

Comment: Also you don't have constraint on putting the function in the code behind of the master. Right? If not, then put the method in the code behind of the master and try again. Ensure the method is declared public.

Comment: Same error. Do I have to add anything to Web.Config or elsewhere?

Comment: Same thing happened after making it public and putting it in code behind

Comment: If I try it without using the `MasterType` directive at the top of the content page, so using `<%= (Page.Master as MasterPageType)...%>` I get an error saying the type or namespace 'MasterPageType' could not be found'

Comment: AHH I got it! If I used the MasterType Directive in my content pages, but instead of doing `<%= Page.Master.fetchContentByID(1).... %>` I do `<%= Master.fetchContentByID(1) %>` it works perfectly. So the `Page.Master` needed to just be `Master.`